# Intel HD graphics adapter

Tags: graphics-card

I am searching for some answers about my laptop's display adapter. I have two graphics which are:

- Intel HD graphics 4000
- Nvidia gf 740m

My laptop is using the Intel HD graphics adapter for display, I tried disabling the Intel HD in device manager and it switched to some Microsoft adapter.

I went in Nvidia control panel and I switched everything from Intel to Nvidia and still no results. What I want to know is if I switch it to Nvidia will I get true colors on my display? If it is yes how can I switch it?

Comment: So just to confirm, you want to use the Nvida adapter as your primary adapter?

Comment: A `Intel HD graphics 4000` is full capable of display true colors.

Comment: Is the actual problem the appearance of colours on the laptop display? If so, can you describe how the appearance is unsatisfactory?